# Step in/on/into the job market?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

I am an international student. I wish to know which of the following I should use.

> 1. Step *into* the job market
> 2. Step *in* the job market
> 3. Step *on* the job market

Comment: So, what do you mean by job market? Is it a building you can physically step into?

Comment: no it is a term describing job and economy.

Comment: You need to understand preposition use in more detail. One random example can only help to leave you confused instead. I invite you to participate in ELL Q&A -- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Comment: You should probably avoid all of them. Just say 'entering the job market' or 'looking for a job'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am graduating from college soon. That means, I will be `stepping into the job market`.

I am thinking of interning for free in my local town office. That would be a `step in the job market`, that would give me credible experience to lift me towards higher steps in my career.

However, I am concerned that politics are in the way towards economic recovery. Those irresponsible politicians and their financial backers do not realise they are `stepping on the job market` crushing our hopes of ever having reasonable employment.

Comment: haha - in this case, giving valid annotated examples of all OP's three different options is the best way to cover everything (I've no doubt he only needed the first though! :)

Answer (score 0):

'Step into' can be used in the sense of entering the job market, even though it is not a physical building as such.